# WP_Query that targets all categories

Tags: posts, wp-query

I've done a bit of `wp_query` work before, but always targeting certain categories.

I want to do a `wp_query` that uses all the categories, but it is not displaying anything.

This is my code:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'nopaging' => false,
    'post_type' => 'posts',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',            
    'meta_key' => 'partner',
    'meta_value' => $post_id
);
```

Nothing is coming through yet and if I add a cat and no:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'nopaging' => false,
    'post_type' => 'posts',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',  
    'cat' => '5',
    'meta_key' => 'partner',
    'meta_value' => $post_id
);
```

It pulls the posts in.

I've searched in Google, but found nothing hence I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly why adding the category changes anything, but... The query looks OK... Almost... There are some things that concerns me:

1. `'post_type' => 'posts',` - there is no built-in post type called `posts`. You should use `post` in there, unless it's your CPT (but then... I don't think it's a good name ;))

This is the biggest concern. But there are some minor ones also:

1. `'posts_per_page' => '4',` - it should be a number, it will be converted, but why should it have to...
2. `'nopaging' => false,` - it's default value for this arg, so there is no point of setting it.

Comment: Hey Krzysiek, thanks for pointing out that posts should have been post.  That has solved it.  I've also remove the no paging too. Cheers :)

Comment: Also the post per page need to be set to 4 as I have styled it up like that in CSS :) have a good day mate!